# Add custom picker sort of controller on UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uipickerview

Please have a look on this application

http://itunes.apple.com/app/yowza-mobile-coupons/id312021877?mt=8

I just want to add custom picker sort of controller on UINavigationBar

Please suggest any sample or ideas

Comment: Hey all developers where are you ? No one have any ideas here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some contextual menus that might work for you in this:

http://mdk.mobilelove.org/home/

they are in .psd format so you'd have to slice them out and customize to your use, but it might get you where you wanna be. hope it helps! jen :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this 
[How to Add Custom UIPickerView to UINavigationBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945526/how-to-add-custom-uipickerview-to-uinavigationbar)

It is from the creator of your example App and here is how to do it thanks to "Mountain Lion"

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:pickerView];
```