# How to Add Custom UIPickerView to UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, uipickerview

I need to add custom picker view to`UINavigationBar` like this. But If I move pickerview to `UINavigationBar` it appears behind `UINavigationBar`.How can I display it correctly above the `UINavigationBar`?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can add like this,

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:pickerView];
```

Hope it will helps you.....

Comment: awesome that worked.but there was another element(searchbox) in my navigation bar. now its not displaying.but left and right bar buttons are displaying correctly. any idea?

Answer (score 4):

You would have to add a custom `UIView` which contains the `UIPickerView` and add it programmatically as the `center view` inside the `UINavigation Controller`. It should load the picker instead of the title for that page.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom view having blue background. Add appropriate views into it.

Hide the navigation bar for this screen.

Comment: Just use the `titleView` property of `UINavigationItem`.

Comment: That would be part of the custom view set as the `titleView`. You don't need to create an entire custom replacement for the nav bar.